# Help with use of Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations in deriving eluer lagrange equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I am having problem with understanding the potential of $y(x)$ being dependent on $\eta(x)$ when using the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations we deriving the formula for euler lagrange equation. I would really appreciate any information you can offer.

I understand the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations:

$\int^b_a y(x)\eta(x)dx =0$ for all $\eta(x)$, then $y(x) = 0$

there are other conditions required, but suppose that if $y(x)$ is dependent on $\eta(x)$

Eg: suppose $y(x) = x + \eta(x)$, then $y(x)$ is dependent on $\eta(x)$. Does the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations allow for this?

I guess not as varying $\eta(x)$, eg: $\eta(x) = 10$, and then $\eta(x) = 11$, $y(x) = x + 10 \neq y(x) = x + 11$ making the $y(x)$ in $\int^b_a y(x)\eta(x)dx =0$ not within the conditions of the lemma
(I am not sure if this is true)

Now for euler lagrangains:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta J}{\delta \alpha} = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\left[\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta f}{\delta y'}\right)\eta(x) \right] dx =0
\end{equation}

Now as $\eta(x)$ (including satisfying the conditions)is arbitary, thus by fundamental Lemma of Variational Calculus,

$\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta f}{\delta y'}\right) = 0$

**My question**

Does $\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta f}{\delta y'}\right)$ never explicitly have $\eta(x)$ such that when varying $\eta(x)$, this $\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta f}{\delta y'}\right)$ does not vary as well? If so does this mean that we can use the fundamental Lemma of Variational Calculus?-or am I wrong?

Comment: "Does the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations allow for this?" No.  You are looking at a single $y(x)$ and EVERY $\eta(x)$, not a family of $y_{\eta}(x)$.

Comment: Thank you so much.
So in that case, $\left(\frac{\delta f}{\delta y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\delta f}{\delta y'}\right)$ cant contain $\eta(x)$ else we could not use the Lemma?

Comment: Correct.  And if you had a $y$ that was built out of other functions, one of which was called $\eta(x)$, then you would use a different variable name for your test functions instead of $\eta(x)$.  The point is that you need to look at your quantifiers used in the statement of the lemma.

Comment: You’re not understanding the logic here. There is no $\eta(x)$ fixed. It is an arbitrary function that you cannot determine. Edit your question to include the exact context.

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe you are referring to the case $\eta(x) = 10,11$? if so, those are just 2 possible values of $\eta(x)$ used to demonstrate my point.

Comment: Your assumption that $y=x+\eta(x)$ is impossible, so of course it leads to nonsense.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I know. The idea was: "suppose there was a $y(x)$ that somehow, was dependent on $\eta(x)$ that the lemma holds?". I gave a random example(hence the fact that I don't know if such existance exists, because if there are none, like Aaron explained, then I could never give an example to begin with).