# Help with Deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a problem with the last step on the proof: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation)

\begin{equation}
\int_a^b\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right]\eta(x) dx =0
\end{equation} where $ε= 0$

Then they apply the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations.

In order to use this lemma, $\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right]$ can not somehow contain $\eta(x)$ implicitly\explicitly.

**My question**

How do we know that $\left[\frac{\partial L}{\partial f} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right]$ does not have $\eta(x)$? is it because we set $ε= 0$ and that all $\eta(x)$ vanishes?

Comment: Look at it. When you write out what it is in full, it's clearly independent of $\eta$ - You can make sense of the expression without referring to $\eta$.

Comment: Interpreting your question literally, you seem to be asking whether $L$ or its derivatives depend on $\eta$, which is a bit weird as a question.  $L$ is fixed before introducing $\eta$, and its derivatives' variables are named $x, f, f'$.  Are you perhaps just needing clarification on how $L_\varepsilon$ [and its derivatives] becomes $L$ [and its derivatives] when $\varepsilon=0$?

Comment: I was wondering that maybe after doing the partial derivatives that we would be left with an exression that has $\eta(x)$ in it, Eg: [lagrange] $ = 3+x \eta(x)$ or something.

Comment: ok I think I see it, when ε $= 0$, the $\eta(x)$ is removed thus we are left with an expressiojn independent of $\eta(x)$.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by the comments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help with use of Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations in deriving eluer lagrange equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576829/help-with-use-of-fundamental-lemma-of-calculus-of-variations-in-deriving-eluer-l)